# Order of pipe operators RXJS Angular 5

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

Is it me, or is the order of my operators not right? In the code below, the two taps with the console.logs return the same values. That can't be right right?

```
return this.pcs.getAvailableMaterials(currentProduct.id).pipe(
            map(
                result => result.result.data
            ),
            tap(
                x => console.log(x, 'before')
            ),
            map(
                materials => {
                    materials.forEach(material => {
                        material.type = 'material'
                    })
                    return materials
                }
            ),
            tap(
                x => console.log(x, 'after')
            ),
            tap(
                materials => {
                    setState({
                        ...state,
                        availableMaterials: materials
                    })
                }
            )
        )
```

Angular 5 application with NGXS.

Comment: What is the type of `this.pcs.getAvailableMaterials(currentProduct.id)`? Is it an RXJS observable?

Comment: Can you make a demo showing what doesn't work as you expect?

Comment: @err1100 Yes the function returns a observable (http call)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**NOTE that @samanime's answer is *not* correct**. Consider the following modification to your original code:

```
return this.pcs.getAvailableMaterials(currentProduct.id).pipe(
        ...
        tap(
            x => console.log(x, 'before')
        ),
        map(
            materials => {
                materials.forEach(material => {
                    material.type = 'material'
                })
                return materials
            }
        ),
        delay(1000), // this line is new
        tap(
            x => console.log(x, 'after')
        ),
        ...
    )
```

You *still* see both logs as the same. For @samanime's answer to be correct, `console.log` would somehow have to be taking a full second to execute, which is certainly not the case.

The issue here is that RXJS expects pipe functions to be *pure*. That is, no pipe function should create any side effects that persist outside the execution of that function. In your first `map` call, you mutate the objects inside the `materials` array and then return a reference to the *same array*. This is a side effect. To fix this, you should be returning a *new* array from the first `map` call. Something like:

```
map(
  materials =>
    materials.map(material => { // map instead of forEach makes a new array
      return {...material, type: 'material'} // object spread makes new objects
    })
)
```

This should give you what you expect.

Comment: Thanks @err1100 editing the second map did the trick! So no more forEach, but maps inside maps.

Comment: Right. The only reason they're "nested" in this case is because your observable is emitting arrays in the first place (as opposed to individual values). So the outer `map` is transforming each array emitted from the observable to some new array, while the inner `map` is a standard JS array map, transforming the _values_ inside each emitted array.